# Count number of change in values in Pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this

```
name    class    date     value
Andy     A      20220101    0 
Andy     A      20220103    1
Andy     A      20220104    0 
Bob      Z      20221120    0 
Bob      Z      20221121    0
Bob      Z      20221125    0
Bob      Z      20221127    1
```

Column `value` only takes value 0 or 1. For each group (defined by 2 columns `name` and `class`), column `date` is order in ascending order. I am trying to calculate for each group the ratio: number of times the column `value` changes in value (0 -> 1 or 1 -> 0) divided by the number of dates with data.

For the above dataframe, group (Andy, A) changes 2 times among 3 days so the ratio is 2/3. Group (Bob, Z) changes 1 time among 4 days so the ratio is 1/4=0.25.

I wonder whether there is a way to do this efficiently in Pandas?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you share code to construct your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
out = (df
       .groupby(['name', 'class']).apply(lambda g: g['value'].shift().bfill().ne(g['value']).sum()/g['date'].nunique())
       .round(2)
       .to_frame('ratio')
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

   name class  ratio
0  Andy     A   0.67
1   Bob     Z   0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
# mark the changes in value
df['changes'] = df['value'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
# count the number of changes and the number of values for each name
aggregated = df.groupby('name').agg({'changes':'nunique', 'value':'size'})
# by construction, we counted the original, so to count the "changes", we must subtract 1
aggregated['changes'] -= 1
# find the ratio
final = aggregated['changes'] / aggregated['value']
name
Andy    0.666667
Bob     0.250000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function that I have been using in my projects.

```
def _count_changes(series):
    """Enumerate the number of value changes in a series"""
    a = series.diff()
    a.iloc[0] = 1
    a.iloc[-1] = 0
    return((abs(a) > 0).cumsum())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values are only 0 and 1. With each change, the absolute value of the difference is always 1. Therefore, you can calculate it using diff.abs.sum/size.

```
df.groupby(['name','class'])['value'].apply(lambda x:x.diff().abs().sum()/x.size)
```